# postfix: force authentication from localhost

Tags: postfix-mta

Commenting

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8

users with shell on system can again send emails using postfix:

main.cf

```
#mynetworks = 
[...]
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_inet_interfaces,

#       reject_sender_login_mismatch,
        reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,

        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
```

So, also put:

```
reject_mynetworks,
```

same problem

I only need force SASL authentication either from lan and from 127.0.0.1 too.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out `mynetworks` implies `postfix` to generate `mynetworks` based on the value of  `mynetworks_style`

So set `mynetworks` to empty string to fix this.